# Elasticsearch: multiple pre_tags/post_tags with fast vector highlighter

Tags: elasticsearch

The documentation includes the following cryptic remark in regards to the pre_tags/post_tags settings capable of containing more than one pair of pre-/post-tags:

> Using the fast vector highlighter there can be more tags, and the
>   "importance" is ordered.

Does anyone know what is the precise meaning of the statement?

Answer (score 3):

It took a while, but by trying different queries using ES 1.7 and the _head plugin I was able to figure out how multiple pre and post tags affect highlighting.

Using the Fast Vector Highlighter, you can specify tags in order of "importance" which seems to mean that their order and the order of your search terms should match. Using more than one pre or post tag to any effect requires more than one field in the query.

Given the index

```
{
 myindex: {
  mappings: {
   corpdocument: {
    properties: {
     createddate: {
      type: "date",
      format: "dateOptionalTime"
     },
     docbody: {
      type: "string",
      analyzer: "text_analyzer",
      fields: {
       exact: {
        type: "string",
        analyzer: "text_analyzer_exact"
       }
      }
     },
     modifieddate: {
      type: "date",
      format: "dateOptionalTime"
     },
     title: {
      type: "string"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

and the Search

```
POST locahost:9200/myindex/corpdocument/_search
{
 "highlight": {
  "pre_tags": ["|primary-highlight|",
  "|secondary-highlight|",
  "post_tags": ["|/primaryh-highlight|",
  "|/secondary-highlight|",
  "fields": {
   "docbody.exact": {
    "fragment_size": 150,
    "number_of_fragments": 3
   }
  }
 },
 "_source": {
  "exclude": ["docbody"]
 },
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "should": [{
    "match": {
     "docbody.exact": {
      "query": "foo"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "match": {
     "docbody.exact": {
      "query": "bar"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

You could get a results like this

```
{
 "took": 14,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
  "total": 5,
  "successful": 5,
  "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
  "total": 97,
  "max_score": 0.48895144,
  "hits": [{
   "_index": "myindex",
   "_type": "corpdocument",
   "_id": "XFxxZWR0ZXN0ZG9jc1xTYW5kYm94XFNhbmRib3hBbGxcRGV4dGVyX2xpdFw3NS5kb2M=",
   "_score": 0.48895144,
   "_source": {
    "createddate": "2010-11-02T00:00:00-05:00",
    "modifieddate": "2007-09-04T00:00:00-05:00",
    "_id": "XFxxZWR0ZXN0ZG9jc1xTYW5kYm94XFNhbmRib3hBbGxcRGV4dGVyX2xpdFw3NS5kb2M="
   },
   "highlight": {
    "docbody.exact": ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit |primary-highlight|foo|/primary-highlight|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit |secondary-highlight|bar|/secondary-highlight|TOTHE|primary-highlight|foo</span>|/primary-highlight|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit |secondary-highlight|bar|/secondary-highlight| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit |primary-highlight|Chief|/primary-highlight| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"]
   }
  },
  ...
  ]
 }
}
```

Which tag wraps which hit is based on the order of the tags and of the search terms. Switch the order of "foo" and "bar" while leaving everything else the same will result in bar being wrapped in the primary tag and foo being wrapped in the secondary tag.

From some initial experiments using 3 search terms with 2 tags it seems like the third terms gets wrapped in the first tag instead of the second. Adding a third tag resolves that problem though requires duplication of the secondary tag n times to cover all the search terms.

```
"highlight": {
 "pre_tags": ["|primary-highlight|",
 "|secondary-highlight|",
 "|secondary-highlight|",
 "post_tags": ["|/primaryh-highlight|",
 "|/secondary-highlight|",
 "|/secondary-highlight|",
 "fields": {
  "docbody.exact": {
   "fragment_size": 150,
   "number_of_fragments": 3
  }
 }
},
..."query": {
 "bool": {
  "should": [{
   "match": {
    "docbody.exact": {
     "query": "foo"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "match": {
    "docbody.exact": {
     "query": "bar"
    }
   }
  },
  {
   "match": {
    "docbody.exact": {
     "query": "baz"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```