# Elasticsearch: FVH highlights with multiple pre and post tags marking tokens incorrectly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying my index using boolean query with two `match` terms. For each term I have a separate set of pre- and post- tags. Using highlights I would like to obtain the documents in which both terms exist and see which tokens were matched as each of them. The index contains documents in Polish analyzed using [morfologik](https://github.com/allegro/elasticsearch-analysis-morfologik). Let's call the two terms I'm searching for `aspect` and `feature`. I want to query the index and retrieve the documents in which both a specific aspect and feature exist and I want the `highlight` feature to mark the aspect token with `<aspect>` tag and the feature with `<feature>` tag. Most of the time it works as expected, sometimes, though, Elasticsearch is marking one or both of the tokens incorrectly. I'll give you an example.

So let's say my index contains the following document:

```
"Najlepsza maseczka na zniszczone włosy!"
```

If I search for "maseczka" (aspect) and "dobry" (feature) I expect the output to be like this:

```
"<feature>Najlepsza</feature> <aspect>maseczka</aspect> na zniszczone włosy! "
```

For some reason the results from Elasticsearch are like this:

```
"<aspect>Najlepsza</aspect> <aspect>maseczka</aspect> na zniszczone włosy! "
```

What I know so far:

- I thought maybe the aspect and feature have similar form when analyzed, but it's not the case, for example `_analyze` for the above example returns:

```
#query
GET my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "morfologik",
  "text": "dobra maseczka"
}

#results
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "dobra",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "dobro",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "dobry",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "maseczka",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
# Analysis of the document:
get my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "morfologik",
  "text": "Najlepsza maseczka na zniszczone włosy"
}
# response
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "dobry",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "maseczka",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "na",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 21,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

- it's also not a problem with specific aspect or feature, because for some queries the index will return both correctly and incorrectly highlighted documents (so I'd expect it to be a problem with documents, rather than queries)
- in some cases both terms are highlighted as aspects, in some aspect is marked as feature and feature as aspect, I haven't found any rule so far
- I thought if my search terms match the order of the highlights tags, the first term should always get the first tag and the second term always the second tag, but maybe they work in a different way? I thought that's how it works inspired by [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38532142/8927822):

  > Using the Fast Vector Highlighter, you can specify tags in order of "importance" which seems to mean that their order and the order of your search terms should match.

Here's how my index is constructed:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "morfologik": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "morfologik_stem",
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "text",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
          "analyzer": "morfologik"
        },
        "original_doc": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match" : { "content" : "maseczki" } }, 
        { "match" : { "content" : "dobre" } }
      ]
  }},
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content": {
        "fragment_size": 200,
        "type": "fvh",
        "pre_tags": ["<aspect>", "<feature>"],
        "post_tags": ["</aspect>", "</feature>"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's a sample response:

```
{
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "R91v7GkB0hUBqPARgC54",
        "_score": 16.864662,
        "_source": {
          "content": "Najlepsza maseczka na zniszczone włosy! ",
          "original_doc_id": 74290
        },
        "highlight": {
          "content": [
            "<aspect>Najlepsza</aspect> <aspect>maseczka</aspect> na zniszczone włosy! "
          ]
        }
      },
```

As I said, most of the time the query works fine and sometimes the all-aspect-highlighting occurs only for a subset of a specific query results, like it does in case of "(opakowanie, solidne)":

- aspect here is in fact feature and feature is aspect

```
<aspect>solidne</aspect>, naprawdę świetne <feature>opakowanie</feature>
```

- `solidne` should be marked as feature here

```
Jedyne do czego mogłabym się przyczepić to <aspect>opakowanie</aspect> które wg mnie niestety nie jest <aspect>solidne</aspect>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding if you want to do a match query on a space separated string, you should be using tokenizer as **whitespace**.

I would suggest you to check this tokenizer. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html

Comment: How does this affect highlighting? The query seems to be working fine (i.e. it finds the documents that contain the tokens I'm looking for). Also, the tokens don't need to form a space separated string, the aspect could also very well be the first word of the document and the aspect could be the last one.

Comment: This does not affect highlighting but can solve your problem of getting of token correct everytime. Also, it doesnt matter if it is first or last word, whitespace tokenizer can detect those also

Comment: Yes, the problem is not with the tokenization, though. The tokens are detected correctly, the problem is with how the tags are applied to them.